# FlyOver is crashing only on iPhone X Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, maps, ios11

I have a pretty strange problem. My app is available for all iPhone's models and just on iPhone X the FlyOver mode is letting the app to crash. Strangely it's not crashing on Xcode simulator but it's doing it on the device, not just on my iPhone X.

The bug is not appearing on any other models with the same iOS version.

Here what the terminal is saying:

```
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537023+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537518+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537691+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537702+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537719+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537744+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537772+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextBeginPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537788+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537814+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537824+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537856+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2018-03-02 14:37:43.537875+0100 ZTL City[3591:990435] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

also sometimes it's returning to me:

```
Metal returned null texture
```

I'm really not able to understand why just on iPhone X it's crashing. Have Apple changed something about the implementation on iPhone X?

Comment: is it on all iOS version, i think this problem was in iOS 11.0, but later fixed in 11.2, have you verified that?

Comment: Actually I don’t know. I tried with iOS 11.2 simulator and it’s working but on iPhone X with iOS 11.2.6 it’s crashing...

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the release of iOS 11.3 Apple has fixed the issue with memory allocation.